# Does the Datadog API support a "partial" update?

Tags: ruby, datadog

I'm looking for a way to do a "partial" update on an existing screenboard/timeboard. By "partial", I mean adding some widget to the existing screenboard/timeboard without wiping out the existing widget that already exist.

Consider the following example:

Create screenboard:

```
require 'dogapi'

api_key = "..."
application_key = "..."

board = {
    "width" => 1024,
    "height" => 768,
    "board_title" => "bjusufbe dogapi test",
    "widgets" => [
        {
          "type" => "image",
          "height" => 20,
          "width" => 32,
          "y" => 7,
          "x" => 32,
          "url" => "https://path/to/create_image.jpg"
        }
    ]
}

dog = Dogapi::Client.new(api_key, application_key)
result = dog.create_screenboard(board)
```

Update screenboard:

```
require 'dogapi'

api_key = "..."
application_key = "..."

board_id = "..."

board = {
    "width" => 1024,
    "height" => 768,
    "board_title" => "bjusufbe dogapi test",
    "widgets" => [
        {
          "type" => "image",
          "height" => 20,
          "width" => 32,
          "y" => 7,
          "x" => 32,
          "url" => "https://path/to/update_image.jpg"
        }
    ]
}

dog = Dogapi::Client.new(api_key, application_key)
result = dog.update_screenboard(board_id,  board)
```

When I run the create and then the update example, the `update_image` widget will overwrite the `create_image` widget and that is the problem I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: The ruby library is just a wrapper around the datadog API. If you take a look at the [main API docs](http://docs.datadoghq.com/api/#screenboards-put), you'll see that only a `PUT` command is listed (i.e. no `PATCH`). So I think that the answer is **no**; you'll need to specify the *full data set* upon an update action.